# Unable to input with keyboard in ptkdb

Tags: perl

I'm using Devel::ptkdb which is provided by Debian package libdevel-ptkdb-perl. The command I used to debug is `perl -dptkdb foo.pl`, where foo.pl is the script being debugged. After the GUI shows up, I can use mouse to click on the buttons or menu items to control the debugging flow, but the keyboard inputs are all ignored. Any idea? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem resolved! It is because perl-tk can't work with input method, if you have any. So the workaround is `XMODIFIERS='' perl -dptkdb foo.pl`, which temporarily disable the input method for perl.